# JAXB XMLElementWrapper with attribute and value

Tags: jaxb

Im trying to create an xml file which is similar looking to the below menetioned.

```
<message>
   <header>
      <params>
         <param name="test1">value1</param>
         <param name="test2">value2</param>
      </params>
   </header>
</message>
```

Can you please let me know, how to define the class hierarchy.

Thanks,
Prakash.A

Comment: The following should help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-complex-types-with-simple.html and http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html

Answer (score 7):

```java
@XmlRootElement
public class Message {

    @XmlElement
    private Header header;
}

public class Header {

    @XmlElement(name="param")
    @XmlElementWrapper
    private Collection<Param> params;
}

public class Param {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;

    @XmlValue
    privaet String value;
}
```

getters/setters on your mark.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use @XmlElementWrapper.
shouled be denoted the name. like @XmlElementWrapper(name="params") though in this situation the default name is the properties's name.